# regarding the authority of past philosophy writers

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics

If some madman who hates philosophy found a way to destroy all works of philosophy where-ever they exist in print or electronically stored so the only 'remembrances' of such work are 'with' a few experts what would happen to Philosophy or Philosophers?? If they 'started over' would they come up with the same lines of arguments as before?

Comment: I think this question, while interesting, is going to prove to be too broad, because it's asking us to speculate about too much. For instance, do we also lose all scientific knowledge (Which is integrated sharply with progress in philosophical understanding)? What else remains similar in this brave new world?

Comment: One possible question is , is the cited authoritative statements made by some previous celebrated philosopher more important than the actual content of the statements involved. A writer could cite two contrary opinions from two 'competing' authoritative schools of thought. If these philosophical doctrines were both highly regarded yet contradictory wouldn't this be a type of epistomological paradox? Could an amateur come out with a brilliant philosophical idea with no authoritative backing?

Comment: @AsphirDom : isn't it a poor logical retort to respond to a person's arguments with a supposedly subtle ( or not) attack on the person's character or previous criticisms about the person. Are you refering to my other question about the words 'Be' and 'Being'.

Comment: @user128932 I don't see my comment anymore. Poor logic you say? :) 99.9 chance you are right.

Comment: The comment was something like ; the mad man is already here; there is no chance of this BE or BEING correct.

Comment: To be more specific if a set of philosophical points of view that are considered very useful are 'lost' or forgotten somehow then are they 'reconstructible' as 'needed' points of view. If they are not that important and not necessarily required for 'proper thinking' might these lesser important 'things' be lost ?

Comment: The way these sites are set up , I guess user - editors don't like to write anything based on opinions. Maybe because opinions can be easily  criticized ( unless they are backed up with a lot of facts or views of other respected authors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, all the most successful philosophy eventually disseminates into the larger culture to the point where it becomes inseparably and invisibly integrated with all the productions of that culture (novels, music, organizational structures, *etc.*).  Therefore, destroying all the works of philosophy would not be enough to entirely destroy the philosophies contained in those works --although a great quantity of valuable ideas could certainly be lost that way.

I would go as far as to say that the biggest danger would be, perhaps, that it would immediately become much harder to counter any idea or ideology that was formulated in such a work, but that had already disseminated into the larger society.

Comment: Speaking in terms of Utilitarianism are there any concepts or principles in Philosophy that actually cause benefitial events or ideas to occur that help people in real tangible ways in their life ; does Philosophy produce real utilizable possibly benefitial results. I imagine Logic does. I saw a book title recently saying something like 'Philosophy can save your life'. Is this an exagertion? Is Philosophy really about molding and arguing about philosophical opinions?

Comment: In terms of directly traceable utility, I'd argue that every science is preceded by a philosopher.  Aristotle preceded Physics, Descartes preceded Newton, Turing preceded modern computing.  One might also argue that all complex social structures are built on a substrate of philosophy, but the causality is a bit harder to prove in that case.

Comment: Every science can be commented on and re-interpreted by philosophers but a sciences basic 'building blocks' where initialized by a lot of empirical observations hopefully relevant to certain 'processes' being observed and also theorizing about what's 'going' on with these processes with the goal of making approximate model's for predictions about the processes. This taking in a lot of empirical data and the 'drive' to make 'accurate prediction models' of various observed processes is what can start a science , not philosophical speculations about the observed processes.

Comment: Let's take my last example, it's recent and uncontroversial.  Without out all the philosophical work poured into the development of modern symbolic logic, and without Alan Turing's brilliant thought experiments, modern computers simply would not be possible.

Comment: But isn't symbolic logic more like the discipline of Mathematics ; couldn't symbolic logic have developed 'along side' algebraic logic or various abstract algebras or even Category theory that is supposed to be of equal importance to Set theory as a fundamental subject in any science. Also Category theory seems to have no literature stating there is any philosophical theories  that are 'foundations' for it. Thought experiments do not seem to be accepted as a real part of science. I mentioned thought experiments on the Physics Stack Exchange and they didn't seem to give them much credence.

Comment: Modern symbolic logic is like mathematics because a group of philosophers put in the work to make that happen.  While it theoretically could have developed as a natural extension of mathematics, I find that improbable.  In general, science makes consistent incremental progress forward, philosophy makes large lateral leaps in thought that may or may not pan out.  As far as thought experiments: Once a science is fully formed, it's much preferable to do real experiments, but when the nascent science is being conceived (by a philosopher!) you do thought experiments instead.

Comment: Why are thought experiments considered so controversial? I thought all sciences 'prided' themselves on their experimental foundations and thought experiments were an aside. I myself love thought experiments ( a bit of a misnomer) and think you can 'see' a lot of possible avenues for 'thought exploration' from them; but other scientists would never consider them even close to a foundation. They act as though nothing is accepted unless experimentally verified.

Comment: There is a fallacy called the 'argument from authority' ,I think were someone makes an argument that is generally regarding the standard  'mutually agreed upon' opinions about some subject that though not being 'proven facts' are treated just as good as empirical facts mainly because of the authority of the person's writing. So the authoritative quality of the writers are considered the defining factors of the info. seeing as the information has a lot of opinions in it.

Comment: Much of philosophy is the continuing conversations and/or emotional debates of authoritative opinions especially regarding unresolved dilemmas. The 'schools of thought' with the most 'generally accepted' opinions are the one's that monopolize the opinion wars and are considered the most reputable even if nothing has been resolved regarding some problem..